# Huawei E303F/E303FH/E303FH not able to connect

Tags: networking, usb-modem

I installed driver for my Huawei E303F/E303FH/E303FH on my Ubuntu 14.04 LST. Installed successfully but not able to connect internet. I tried to fallowed a document which come with Huawei E303F/E303FH/E303FH for Linux installation. But not able able to connect.No connection available. Same Huawei E303F/E303FH/E303FH working fine on windows 8.1.